# Cloud Function - Checking if a token has expired

Tags: node.js, reactjs, function, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How do I check if a Google API access token is expired?

Using [Nodejs Google Api Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) and successfully get a refresh and access token on login. However, I'm running into issues when the access token expires after 1 hour.

I created a function that checks whether the token is expired or not with each API call. This works until the token expires in which case it throws an error:

`const tokenInfo = await oauth2Client.getTokenInfo(req.params.accessToken);`

The library has a function which is supposed to auto-refresh the token. However, it does not work with my implementation.

Essentially, I'm just looking for a function that returns a boolean true/false when the token expires and then I can handle everything from there. Is there a way I can set this up? Thanks for the help!

```
router.get("/api/tokenrefresh/:userId/:accessToken", async function (req, res) {

    //Library auto-refresh function. Nothing ever console logs. 
    oauth2Client.on("tokens", (tokens) => {
      if (tokens.refresh_token) {
        console.log(tokens.refresh_token);
      }
      console.log(tokens.access_token);
      req.params.accessToken = tokens.access_token
      res.json({
        refreshNeeded: true,
        token: tokens.access_token,
      });
    });

    //my logic to check status of token. Works until token expires then throws error
    const tokenInfo = await oauth2Client.getTokenInfo(req.params.accessToken);

    console.log(tokenInfo.expiry_date);
    console.log(Date.now());

    console.log('DIFFERENT IN TIMES', tokenInfo.expiry_date - Date.now());

    res.json({
      refreshNeeded: false,
    });
```

Comment: Google Api access token  <-- only way is to use it if the api returns an error then you know its expired.

Comment: I thought of that but was concerned if an error is thrown for a reason other than the token expiration. Unless (now I'm thinking out loud), wrapping just that function in a try catch like: ```try {    const tokenInfo = await oauth2Client.getTokenInfo(req.params.accessToken);
} catch(error) {//refresh the token}``` Edit: I'm going to test that out. I think that might do it.

Answer (score 2):

While the expiry time in the token is mostly accurate, you cannot rely on it as tokens can expire earlier. Calling the token info endpoint before each request is generally also not a good idea since it can result in unwanted additional latency and potentially hammering the endpoint for high frequency APIs (like for example Bigtable)

The best practice is to actually try the request you want to do - and in the error handler just attempt a refresh for the appropriate error code. Make sure you have limits for your retries to avoid risking an endless loop in case you consistently hit errors.

Also, while I'm not 100% sure what kind of framework you are using, the code you posted looks dangerous to me: You should never have an endpoint in your API/website where one can retrieve access tokens for any user ID. This is equal to an account compromise. Refresh- and access tokens confer access powers if compromised / leaked and thus have to be handled with care.

Comment: Regarding your 3rd point on code safety, how would I pass the updated token from the backend to the front-end for the current user? The biggest issue I'm running into is having the current user ID so I can update the right row in Postgres. Would a static route like: `/api/token` and then passing required userid as body info still pose a security risk? Another thought I had was to pass the id in a separate route and then store that as a variable in Node. From there just use that variable instead of passing `userId` as a param or body element. Thoughts on how to best go about this?

Comment: If you're calling APIs from a web app, have a look at this: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow